# Why wont this menu get aligned in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a menu that would be fixed in the middle of the page.
The menu is of `1170px` in width and `30px` in height with a blue line at the bottom.
Now....I'd like to make it a menu that is positioned in the middle of the page with the rest of the items on the page.

Align: center doesnt seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div align="center;" id="menu"> 
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nuestros Cursos</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
</ul> <!-- end inner UL-->
</li> <!-- end main LI-->
</ul> <!-- end main UL-->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Preparación de exámenes</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
</ul> <!-- end inner UL-->
</li> <!-- end main LI-->
</ul> <!-- end main UL-->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Estudiar en el Extranjero</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
</ul> <!-- end inner UL-->
</li> <!-- end main LI-->
</ul> <!-- end main UL-->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Quienes somos</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
</ul> <!-- end inner UL-->
</li> <!-- end main LI-->
</ul> <!-- end main UL-->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Trabaja con nosotros</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
</ul> <!-- end inner UL-->
</li> <!-- end main LI-->
</ul> <!-- end main UL-->
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*-----------------------new menu I am working on------------------------*/

#menu {

width:1170px;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
margin-left: auto; /*margin left es right fontosak olyan szinten hogy amit meretnek valasztok a menure...azt szepent automatikusan kozepre helyezi*/
margin-right: auto;
border-bottom:solid 3px #289dcb; /*#68bc1d szep zold szint jelent*/
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
    }

#menu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#3b3b3b; /*colours the menu and also the submenu background*/
    }

#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFF; /*colour of the text in the menu*/
    border:1px solid #000;
    }

#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute; /* this is what orders the nested links to appear in a block under the main ul*/
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
    }

#menu ul li:hover ul { /* this is what makes the dropdown menu appear on hovering over it*/
    visibility:visible;
    }

#menu li:hover {
    background:#ff5454; /* main menu box changes to this color (also the submenus) on hovering over it, red in this case*/
    }
```

here is what it looks like: **[Demo js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97zXb/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS will do the trick. [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/tojag/1/edit)

I didn't use `display: inline-block` because it will give you gap between each `<li>`.

Instead i have used `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to make it align properly without any gaps in between list.

[image]

```
#menu {
width: 1170px;
height: 30px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-bottom: solid 3px #289dcb;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
display: table;
}

#menu ul {
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
line-height: 30px;
display: table-cell;
}

#menu li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;
background: #3b3b3b;
width: 100%;
}
#menu ul li a {
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is one more thing I am wondering about.....I am also learning about how to position containers.....but is there a turorial or a way to use, say 1170px, width and apply it to the whole site? I would like to create a center positioned, uniformly 1170 px width site.

Comment: To have a centered positioned site with 1170px width follow the steps: 1. create a wrapper after the <body> tag and put all your content within the wrapper. 2. Add css for the wrapper as #wrapper { width: 1170px; margin: auto;} this will align your wrapper to the center of the page. 3. Now you can add any divs for header, content and sidebar within this wrapper. Everything will be aligned in the center of the page :)

Comment: @Elysium - note this leaves you with potentially redundant HTML you'll need to clean up

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to add the following line to the css for #menu ul and it will center your menu.

```
    display: inline-block;
```

Here is a modified version of your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97zXb/5/).

Comment: Your sollution messed up the line-up of the dropdowns though.

Answer (score 1):

You actually require modification to both your HTML and CSS:

Crucial points:

1. You were adding successive lists to `#menu` where you only need one, with child `li` for each menu item
2. `text-align:center` needed to be added to `#menu` and `display:inline-block` to `#menu ul` for centering to happen

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/97zXb/6/)

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nuestros Cursos</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Preparación de exámenes</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Estudiar en el Extranjero</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Quienes somos</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabaja con nosotros</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Spanish</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">French</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul {
    height: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #289dcb;
    /*#68bc1d szep zold szint jelent*/
    ;
}
#menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #3b3b3b;
    /*colours the menu and also the submenu background*/
    ;
}
#menu a {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    /*colour of the text in the menu*/
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    /* this is what orders the nested links to appear in a block under the main ul*/
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 32px;
    left:0;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    /* this is what makes the dropdown menu appear on hovering over it*/
    visibility: visible;
}
#menu li:hover {
    background: #ff5454;
    /* main menu box changes to this color (also the submenus) on hovering over it, red in this case*/
    ;
}
```

Comment: Right....so, I was not supposed to use "</ul> <!-- end inner UL-->
</li> <!-- end main LI-->
</ul> <!-- end main UL-->" and close each line in the html. Thanks a lot. It works just fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the given css and try, hope it will work fine

```
#menu {
width:1170px;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
margin-left: auto; /*margin left es right fontosak olyan szinten hogy amit meretnek valasztok a menure...azt szepent automatikusan kozepre helyezi*/
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:solid 3px #289dcb; /*#68bc1d szep zold szint jelent*/
    }
```